# What is the set of any font in Gnome-Tweak-Tool?

Tags: fonts, gnome-tweak-tool

[image]

I know that:

Default font-is just default
Document font-for Documents
Window title fonts is for titles.

What the others are for? What is monospace font? I only know it's a font like any font.

Hinting is for notices like the names of objects in the dock, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ubuntu Unity desktop allows fonts to be specified for a number of different display categories:

- *Application font* - The font used to display text in application windows. This also changes the font used to display items such as the menus in the desktop panel.
- *Document font* - Specifies the font that is to be used when displaying document text in an application.
- *Desktop font* - The font used to display text under the icons on the desktop (such as folder names).
- *Window title font* - The font used on the text in window titles.
- *Fixed width / Monospace font* - Specifies the font to be used when the system needs to display a fixed width font. A prime example of this is the text that is rendered in a Terminal window.
- *Default font* - As its name implies, the widely used font.

Comment: i still didn't get what is the monospace font, my items in the desktop in ubuntu font, as it says ubuntu mono.

Comment: @yinon See the bullet before the last one which explains what is this font (terminal)

Comment: "fixed width / Monospace font" ok, it just i saw it's first name